# How to draw board 3d? GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut

I know how to draw rectangles, but I want to draw board. **It will be part** of my map where I wanted to create maze. It should be 3D. So I need to create simple board. I know that I need to create it using polygons. Can someone help?

```
glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );     glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );      // P1 is red
  glColor3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );     glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );      // P2 is green
  glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );     glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );      // P3 is blue
  glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );     glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );      // P4 is purple

  glEnd();

  // White side - BACK
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(   1.0,  1.0, 1.0 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, 0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, 0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
  glEnd();

  // Purple side - RIGHT
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(  1.0,  0.0,  1.0 );
  glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
  glEnd();

  // Green side - LEFT
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(   0.0,  1.0,  0.0 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
  glEnd();

  // Blue side - TOP
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(   0.0,  0.0,  1.0 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
  glEnd();

  // Red side - BOTTOM
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  glColor3f(   1.0,  0.0,  0.0 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
  glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
  glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
  glEnd();
```

It will draw a simple cube, but I need to transform it to the board. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do, and where you're getting stuck?

Comment: I want to create a board, something like http://www.codemiles.com/c-opengl-examples/opengl-shadow-mapping-example-t9453.html in the bottom pictures. I need a cube which would be like a board. Later I will put some walls on this board to make a room. ( If it is not clear, board looks like a chess board but without textures. It should be a board like a floor to my map. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your cube appear like the board (or floor) you described, you've got two main options.

The first is simply to change the coordinates of your polygons. At the moment, your cube runs from -0.5 to 0.5 on each axis. You could change the coordinates to run from e.g. -5.0f to 5.0f on X and Z, and -10.0f, to -9.0f on Y.

If you're not sure how to do that, it involves changing the numbers in the `glVertex3f()` calls. The parameters are in this order: X, Y, Z.

The second option is to use matrix transformations. A translation can move the cube downwards towards the floor, and a scale can stretch it out sideways:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.0f, -9.5f, 0.0f); // move downwards
glScalef(10.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f); // stretch on X and Z

// insert your cube drawing code here

glPopMatrix();
```

The push/pop calls are there to prevent the matrix transformations from affecting other drawing, or from accumulating each time your drawing code is executed.

Comment: Thank you. And what about object? Then I put it and execute it, there is only a black screen.  I always get a problem with reshape() function, sometimes I hit proper settings... By the way, should I use glLoadIdentity() before using transformation?

Comment: If it's only showing a black screen then it's possible the polygons have gone off the edge of the screen. You'll probably need to look at a tutorial on setting up a camera view/matrix. (There's not enough room to explain it in these comments.)